# The return values for inputSex() and inputAge() arent returning anything?

Tags: c, output

I am trying to input an int or char into functions and return that value but neither of them are returning anything. I have tried putting print statements in both functions and they both print out something but the function wouldnt return anything. Any information will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
#include "defs.h"
#define MAX_CHAR 32

int nameInput(char firstName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char middleInt[2], char 
lastName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char suffix[4]);
int printName(char firstName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char middleInt[2], char 
lastName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char suffix[4]);
void emptyStdin(void);
int inputAge(int min, int max);
char inputSex(void);
int printAge(int age);
char printSex(char sex);

int main (void)
{
         int choice = 0, age = 0;
         char firstName[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0}, middleInt[2] = {0}, 
         lastName[MAX_CHAR + 1] = {0}, suffix[4] = {0};
         char sex = '\0';

    do
    {
            printf("Menu\n");
            printf("1. Name\n");
            printf("2. Enter Years, Party, Office, and State \n");
            printf("3. Enter Age and Sex\n");
            printf("4. Enter Contacts \n");
            printf("5. Enter Contributions and Lies \n");
            printf("6. Display Data \n");
            printf("7. Clear all Data \n");
            printf("8. Quit\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            switch (choice)
            {
                    case 1:
                            emptyStdin();
                            nameInput(firstName, middleInt, lastName, suffix);
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            emptyStdin();
                            inputAge(21,99);
                            emptyStdin();
                            inputSex();
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            break;
                    case 5:
                            break;
                    case 6:
                            printName(firstName, middleInt, lastName, suffix);
                            printAge(age);
                            printSex(sex);
                            break;
                    case 7:
                            break;
                    case 8:
                            choice = 8;
                            break;
                    default:
                            printf("Input is invalid\n");
                            break;
            }
    } while(choice != 8);

return (0);
}

int  nameInput(char firstName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char middleInt[2], char 
lastName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char suffix[4])
{
    char temp[2] = {0};
    int c = 15;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Type in the politicians first name (max 32 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", firstName);
    emptyStdin();

    printf("Type in the politicians middle initial. If none type 0. (max 1 character): ");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    c = temp[i];
    c = temp[i];

    if(c == 0)
    {
            middleInt[i] = '\0';
    }
    if(c != 0)
    {
            strcpy(middleInt, temp);
    }
    else;
    emptyStdin();

    printf("Type in the politicians last name (max 32 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", lastName);
    emptyStdin();

    printf("Type in the politicians suffix. If none type 0. (max 3 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", suffix);
    emptyStdin();
    printf("\n\n");
return 1;
}

int printName(char firstName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char middleInt[2], char 
lastName[MAX_CHAR + 1], char suffix[4])
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("*****Unknown/Not Applicable if the output is a 0*****\n\n");
    printf("- Politicians first name: ");
    for (i = 0; i != ('\n' || '\0'); i++)
    {
            printf("%s", &firstName[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    i = 0;
    printf("- Politicians middle initial: ");
    if (middleInt[i] != '\0')
    {
            for (i = 0; i != ('\n' || '\0'); i++)
            {
                    printf("%s", &middleInt[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    else;

    i = 0;
    printf("- Politicians last name: ");
    for (i = 0; i != ('\n' || '\0'); i++)
    {
            printf("%s", &lastName[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    i = 0;
    printf("- Politicians suffix: ");
    if (suffix[i] != 0)
    {
            for (i = 0; i != ('\n' || '\0'); i++)
            {
                    printf("%s", &suffix[i]);
            }
    }
    else;

    printf("\n");

return 1;
}

void emptyStdin(void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
           {
            c = getchar();
    }
}

int inputAge(int min, int max)
{
    int age = 0, i = 0;
    printf("Enter the age of the politician [Between 21 and 99]: ");

    i = 1;
    for(i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
            scanf("%d", &age);
            if (age < min || age > max)
            {
                    printf("That number isnt in the range. Please try again. \n");
                    i--;
            }
            else
            {
                    break;
            }
    }

return age;
}

char inputSex(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char sex;

    i = 1;
    printf("Enter the sex of the politician [Choose either M or F]: ");
    for(i = 1; i < 2; i++)
    {
            scanf("%c", &sex);
            if(sex == 'M' || sex == 'F')
            {
                   {
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("That is not a vaild input. Please try again.");
                    i--;
            }
    }
return sex;
}

int printAge(int age)
{
    printf("- Age: %d\n", age);
return 1;
}

char printSex(char sex)
{
    printf("- Sex: %d\n", sex);
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's where you're calling `inputAge`...

```
inputAge(21,99);
```

...notice anything missing? You're not storing the return value anywhere. If you want it to store the result into `age` (based on the call to `printAge` a few lines down), you need to change that line to this.

```
age = inputAge(21,99);
```

Same goes for the call to `inputSex` too.

Comment: ... and the fact that the `inputAge()` and `inputSex()` have their own local variables `age` and `sex`, respectively, has no bearing on the issue.  Local variables are local.

Answer (score 0):

In your `case` statement, you are calling the `inputAge` and `inputSex` functions, but you aren't assigning their return values to variables.

```
case 3:
  emptyStdin();
  age = inputAge(21,99);
  emptyStdin();
  sex = inputSex();
  break;
```